# Include Library mylibrary.a into Podspec

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have generated a library `mylibrary.a` which I want to ship with a pod. The header files are in

```
/pathToLibDir/headers
```

The only sources I have is `mylibrary.a` there are no other files. `mylibrary.a` is located in

```
/pathToLidDir/lib
```

Here is my **podspec** file I created. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = 'podnamen'
s.version = '1.0'
s.summary = 'summary.'
s.public_header_files = '/pathToLibDir/headers/*.h'
s.requires_arc = true
s.libraries = 'mylibrary'
s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '/otherpath/include /pathToLidDir/lib', 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => 'otherpath/include /pathToLidDir/headers' }
end
```

**How do I integrate `mylibrary.a` into the podspec and make the public headers from `/pathToLibDir/headers` available in the pod? Do I have to use `vendored_libraries`?**

Comment: Why do you want to ship the static library directly? Do you want to keep the source code private?

Comment: I generated this lib and want to keep source code private. Yes.

Comment: Your podspec looks ok - is the library in the headers directory?

Comment: no the lib is in ``/pathToLidDir/lib``. Do I have to use ``vendored_libraries``?

Comment: LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS should point to the directory containing the static library. You might also want to add that directory to `preserve_path`. In that way, Cocoapods won't consider the static library as junk. Card.IO (Paypal) is a very good example ([link to podspec](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/CardIO.podspec))

Comment: How do I specify more than one path in ``HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS``? Is it the correct way how I did it?

Comment: You don't need to specify the headers search path. It's done automatically for you by Cocoapods. You should use `source_files` to specify the headers. If you have a look at that podspec I've posted in my previous comment everything will be clear.

Comment: The question was how do I specify more than one path in for example LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS?

Answer (score -1):

You can look to other libraries examples: [example_1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/a2c9eca00f5defc6e9b280423829a9e332c94100/Specs/wywyTVA/0.0.5/wywyTVA.podspec.json) [example_2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/b1ae5926beb0daa3060113981f3ada98cca292a6/Specs/DFJPEGTurbo/0.1.0/DFJPEGTurbo.podspec.json) [more_examples](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=vendored_libraries)